# Error occured while running task Cap deploy:setup During deployment using Capistrano with Unicorn

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is error which occurs after running task Cap deploy:setup to deploy ubuntu server using Capistrano and Unicorn. Please help me out here if you know the answer?
here is error reflecting on terminal-

[100.116.4.74] sh -c 'cp -RPp /home/deployer/apps/mcash/shared/cached-copy /home/deployer/apps/mcash/releases/20120417074244 && (echo 8f69f0a524dcecef478bad74df4a983d3cdad480 > /home/deployer/apps/mcash/releases/20120417074244/REVISION)'
 ** [out :: 100.116.4.75] cp: cannot create directory `/home/deployer/apps/mcash/releases/20120417074244'
 ** [out :: 100.116.4.75] : No such file or directory

failed: "sh -c 'cp -RPp /home/deployer/apps/mcash/shared/cached-copy /home/deployer/apps/mcash/releases/20120417074244 && (echo 8f69f0a524dcecef478bad74df4a983d3cdad480 > /home/deployer/apps/mcash/releases/20120417074244/REVISION)'" on 100.116.4.74

Here is entire deploy.rb file-

require "bundler/capistrano"

```
role :web,    "200.116.4.75"
role :app,    "200.116.4.75"
role :db,     "200.116.4.75", :primary => true

set :application,     "mcasher"
set :user,            "deployer"
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :use_sudo,        false

set :scm,             :git
set :repository,      "git-server:mcasher.git"
set :branch,          "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: I had used this link in order to deploy application on ubuntu   https://medrails.wordpress.com/?blogsub=confirming#subscribe-blog